# What are the advantages and disadvantages of using Jquery UI with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs

I have a Web application in line and i am planing to use JqueryUI and AngularJS in my ASP.NET MVC project.Is this a right choice.

Is there any suitable Databinding library that i can use with JQuery UI.Please also specify the advantages over AngularJS.

Any help is appretiated.

Comment: Can't give you a decent, fully formed answer, but one disadvantage is page weight - jQuery UI isn't exactly lean, and when you combine that with Angular, you're going to be sending a lot of stuff down the pipe, so you'll end up with something pretty slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to grab the benefits of angular js, it's recommended to use angular-ui which uses twitter bootstrap in angular way.

Read about angular-ui here http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Like @BenLanc commented the jquery-ui will make you slow.